# Loop Through a Table to concatenate Rows

Tags: sql, vertica, string-aggregation

I have a table of similar structure:

```
Name Movies_Watched
A    Terminator
B    Alien
A    Batman
B    Rambo
B    Die Hard

....
```

I am trying to get this:

```
Name  Movies_Watched
A     Terminator;Batman
B     Alien, Die Hard, Rambo
```

My initial guess was:

```
SELECT Name, Movies_Watched || Movies_Watched from TABLE
```

But obviously that's wrong. Can someone tell me how can I loop through the 2nd column and concatenate them? What's the logic like?

Got to know that group_concat is the right approach. But haven't been able to figure it out yet. When I've tried:

```
select name, group_concat(movies_watched) from table group by 1
```

But it throws an error saying **User-defined transform function group_concat must have an over clause**

Comment: [According to the manual](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Functions%7CAggregate%2520Functions%7C_____20) Vertica support `listagg()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, in Vertica it's LISTAGG():

```
WITH
input(nm,movies_watched) AS (
          SELECT 'A','Terminator'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','Alien'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','Batman'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','Rambo'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','Die Hard'
)
SELECT
  nm AS "Name"
, LISTAGG(movies_watched) AS movies_watched
FROM input
GROUP BY nm;
-- out  Name |    movies_watched    
-- out ------+----------------------
-- out  A    | Terminator,Batman
-- out  B    | Alien,Rambo,Die Hard
-- out (2 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (2 rows): 12.735 ms. All rows formatted: 12.776 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `string_agg()`:

```
select name, string_agg(movie_watched, ';') as movies_watched
from t
group by name;
```

That said, you are using Postgres, so you should learn how to use arrays instead of strings for such things.  For instance, there is no confusion with arrays when the movie name has a semicolon.  That would be:

```
select name, array_agg(movie_watched) as movies_watched
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I'm getting this error: [VERTICA][JDBC](3457) ERROR: Function array_agg(varchar)) does not exist or permission is denied

Comment: @fthedevs: if you are using Vertica, then why did you add the `postgresql` tag?

Comment: pardon me, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

use array_agg

```
SELECT Name, array_agg(Movies_Watched)
FROM data_table
GROUP BY Name
```

i think you need listagg or group_concat as you are using vertica upper is postgrey solution

```
SELECT Name, listagg(Movies_Watched) 
FROM data_table
GROUP BY Name
```

or

```
 select Name, 
 group_concat(Movies_Watched) over (partition by Name order by name) ag
 from mytable
```

Comment: `string_agg()` is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I'm getting this error: [VERTICA][JDBC](3457) ERROR: Function array_agg(varchar)) does not exist or permission is denied

Comment: @fthedevs in vertica i think group_concat is need

Comment: i've tried: seelct name,group_concat(movies_Watched) from table group by 1
but it shows an error that User-defined transform function group_concat must have an over clause